# MySQL max databases count

Tags: mysql

How many databases supports MySQL?
Is it limited only by used file system?

The problem is creating sub-sites on project subdomains with the same functional but different scope.
An applicable solution is creating new database each time for each subdomain, but I'm not sure about it.

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much data is stored in the database, how the queries are optimized/written, and how many people visit your websites.

If you are hosting on a shared server it can also be limited by your hosting provider.

Comment: And instead of creating new databases you might consider creating new tables in a database, or, create new records within an existing table.